# Replacing the Windows shell with a WPF app

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi, shell, windows-7

I want to replace Windows 7 Shell (32 and 64 bit) with my WPF application which should work as a Shell. The goal is WPF application will launch my Kiosk application and provide few services.

My questions are

1. How do I replace the Windows 7 Shell by my
   WPF application ?
2. Do I have to do
   something special in my WPF
   application code or required
   registry changes to execute WPF
   application as a shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) Change the user's Registry entry at **HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell** -- it is a REG_SZ type (that is, a string) which expects the full path to the executable. (A little more info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx)--it says it's for XP-Embedded, but the how-to is good for Win7 as well.)

2.) No, you don't need to do anything special in your app--just be sure that users *can* get to all the commands you need to (e.g. log off) and *not* get to the ones you want to avoid. If I recall correctly, the computer's Ctrl-Alt-Del behavior doesn't change with a custom shell, so you can use that to get your logoff/shutdown commands as well as Task Manager.

Comment: cool thanks for answer I will try this. One more question along the same line is I want to keep the launched application always on the top and nobody should take over like Kiosk, Is the Z-order will enough for that?

Comment: You can set TopMost for WPF windows, that's usually enough.

Comment: I have had focus issues with this solution. Is there anything special to be done?

Comment: @yeyeyerman Can you explain more what you mean by "focus issues"? (You might want to make it another question if you want more help with it.)