# First key press lost when Windows Shell is replaced with Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have succesfully replaced the Windows Shell following the approach given in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3702664/110466).

However, I have detected that the first key press is lost and is a bit of an annoyance for the user. The solution we have tried is to activate the form in the OnShown event:

```
private void OnShownLoginForm(object z_sender, EventArgs z_e)
{
    Activate();
    m_loginTextBox.Focus();
}
```

But this hasn't solved the problem.  Do you have any clue of what is happening?

Comment: do you have any kind of keypress keydown event handler on the form or on the textbox? does the problem happen only the first time and how can you reproduce (click on form then on textbox, does it work)?

Comment: It is not easy to reproduce, as the only keypress that gets lost is the first one. The situation is the following: at the end of system boot-up the application gets displayed, asking for a login. Then, when users try to write their credentials, the first keypress won't write anything. The rest will work without problem.

Comment: Was my answer of any benefit?  Please mark the question as answered or respond.  If my suggestion does not work, I have a couple other thoughts that might work.

Comment: can't you see if a previewKeypressEvent on the parent form can detect the input?

Comment: How about creating an Idle handler that dumps out the focussed control? I am pretty sure the textbox does not have the focus initially, and only after the first keypress, the focus is set up correctly. So focussing the textbox in the OnShow event might make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys Class` ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)) to send a key press event to the form when in the Form Load event.  If that doesn't help, try sending the keyboard events in the Form.Shown event since Form.Shown is the last event in the form start-up process.

Comment: You mean from the application to the application?

Comment: Correct, but I would send it specifically to a control on your form.  (Say, the text box that the user may enter their ID.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something caused by maybe another control getting focus first. Does the textbox have a taborder, and can you set it to 0? Focus should then be on it after the form loads.

Otherwise try creating a new form to test with, it really doesn't seem reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if it is related but I had a similar problem where the tabindex property of a webform did not work by pressing the TAB key, after focusing on the first input at page load, until the user first clicked on the form with the mouse.

I did not have access to the source code so I tried solving it with javascript.
Until the first mouse click, all keyboard strokes, including the TAB key, activated the keypress event, TAB key was undetected by keydown/keyup on page load.

I learned that the TAB key activated the keypress event and I could access the keycode through it. simply registering the keypress event and manually switching to the next input with jQuery worked.
after the first mouse click the form behaved as expected, TAB key was no longer caught by  keypress event.

here is a code sample:

```
function tabNext(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 9){
        // do work
    }
}

$('input').keypress(tabNext);
```