# Change Win 7 Shell for non-admin user account with autologon

Tags: wpf, windows, shell, admin

I need a WPF app to run in 'kiosk mode' and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702664/replacing-the-windows-shell-with-a-wpf-app) looks like the way to do it. But I'm not clear on a couple of issues:

Does the user account I want to replace the shell for have to be an admin account? Or can I do this for a non-admin account from my admin account?

Once the shell is changed, can I still use autologon? The machine will restart each morning and I want it to go straight to the app.

If I change the shell and use autologon, how can I logon as a different user?

The app is a multitouch app and there won't be a physical keyboard present. It's Windows 7 but I'm not sure if it's Enterprise or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kiosk account should not be an administrator.

That's a user registry key (it starts with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) so no special privilege is required.  You can make this change from the kiosk user account itself, or, if the kiosk user account is logged in, you can do it from the admin account - go to `HKEY_USERS` and look for the key associated with the kiosk account.  If you know the kiosk account's SID you can find the right key that way, otherwise just use trial and error - the Environment subkey for each user contains their username.

Having a custom shell will not interfere with autologon.

You can bypass autologon by pressing the SHIFT key just before the logon screen appears.  You may need to tap it repeatedly to get the timing right.  Alternatively, if the machine has a network connection, you could use Remote Desktop to log in remotely.